# Cannot get paragraph's innerHTML from a page inside <iframe>

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, innerhtml, paragraph

I am trying to get a paragraph's innerHTML, so I can check if it matches a certain one and then send the user to another page, depending on what the result is. How can I fix this?

```
var input = document.getElementById('serial').value;
    var validator = document.createElement('iframe');
    validator.src = "http://awebsite.com/wvkey=" + input;
    body.appendChild(validator);
    var status = validator.contentWindow.document.getElementById('status').innerHTML;
    if (status === "Key Status: Active") {
        window.location.assign("../dashboard/index.html");
    }
    else {
        window.location.assign("../support/keys/invalid/index.html");
    }
```

Note: Ignore that 'body' variable, it's declared earlier in the code. The iframe and the page itself appear but they don't work as intended, they don't send the user anywhere.

Comment: I guess I was late with hiding my website, ha-ha. Don't worry, I'm just testing it there, I will pay for a GOOD hosting later.

Comment: @Barmar, it was the original link in the code. I decided to hide it with a fake one.

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the main page? If not, they can't access each other.

Comment: No, they are not, it's stored in an Electron app. So I guess that's the issue, great, now I'll have to do it ALL OVER AGAIN. Thanks for pointing it out at least lol